# How can I disable specified request to refresh session timeout in spring/servlet/struts2 framework?

Tags: java, spring, http, tomcat, servlets

here is the case:
I run a web app in tomcat, the session timeout is 15 minutes.

So all request will refresh it's session timeout.

I have a request from front-end with path "/not/refresh/sessiontimeout"

I want "/not/refresh/sessiontimeout" request do not refresh session timeout.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can not, but you can modify the session's length to obtain a similar effect:

```java
final HttpServletRequest req = ...;
final HttpSession session = req.getSession();
final long idleTimeMs = Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - session.getLastAccessedTime();
final int maxInactiveSec = session.getMaxInactiveInterval() - (int)(idleTimeMs / 1000);
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(maxInactiveSec);
```

Comment: Thanks, I also think about similar solution, and will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

At first, create custom classes:

```
    public class CustomSessionRegistryImpl extends SessionRegistryImpl {
        private Set<String> disabledNextRefreshRequests = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    
        public CustomSessionRegistryImpl() {
            super();
        }
    
        public void preventNextRefreshLastRequest(String sessionId) {
            Assert.hasText(sessionId, "SessionId required as per interface contract");
            disabledNextRefreshRequests.add(sessionId);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void refreshLastRequest(String sessionId) {
            Assert.hasText(sessionId, "SessionId required as per interface contract");
    
            SessionInformation info = getSessionInformation(sessionId);
    
            if (info != null && !disabledNextRefreshRequests.contains(sessionId)) {
                info.refreshLastRequest();
            }
            disabledNextRefreshRequests.remove(sessionId);
        }
    }
```

```
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class CustomPreConcurrentSessionFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
        @Autowired
        private final SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
    
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                SessionInformation info = sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(session.getId());
                if (info != null && !info.isExpired() && sessionRegistry instanceof CustomSessionRegistryImpl) {
                    boolean shouldPrevent = URL_IGNORE_UPDATE_SESSION_LIFETIME.contains(request.getServletPath());
                    if (shouldPrevent) {
                        ((CustomSessionRegistryImpl) sessionRegistry).preventNextRefreshLastRequest(info.getSessionId());
                    }
                }
                if (info != null && !info.isExpired()
                        && (new Date().getTime() - info.getLastRequest().getTime())/1000 >= session.getMaxInactiveInterval()
                ) {
                        //the session has timed out
                        info.expireNow();
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
```

and then inside @Configuration

```
    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new CustomSessionRegistryImpl();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public GenericFilterBean getCustomPreConcurrentSessionFilter() {
        return new CustomPreConcurrentSessionFilter(sessionRegistry());
    }

    ...
    http.sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(-1)
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    http.addFilterBefore(getCustomPreConcurrentSessionFilter(), ConcurrentSessionFilter.class);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).